# Manga where a student sees a mascot and was thrown out the school building

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

A student sees a mascot outside their school and was the attacked by it and then he wake up into another world. Then there is also a scene where the student wakes up from coma and again sees the mascot outside the window and the mascot attacked him again.

Comment: Is this someone who looks like they're in a mascot costume? Or is it a flesh-and-blood creature that looks like a mascot? And when they wake from the coma, are they still in another world, or is that them waking up to the "real world" before being attacked by the mascot again?

Answer (score 1):

The description is too vague, but if you were looking for "[Parallel Paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Paradise)" (18+), then I can understand why you left out the details.

> Youta Tada is an ordinary high school student who holds deep feelings for his childhood friend. One day during class, he is suddenly attacked and seemingly killed by a mysterious scarecrow-like being. Youta then wakes up and finds himself in an alternate world with castles, dragons and two colored moons in a purple sky. Here he meets paladin girl Lumi and a three-legged bird named Genius and quickly learns that he got into a women-only world where he is the first man that appeared in centuries. Thanks to that, females in this world have absolutely no resistance towards him and his single touch makes Lumi incredibly aroused. Genius then orders him to mate with her and all other girls in this fantastical world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be _Parallel Paradise_ i.e. the ways in which it matches the manga described in the question. It'd help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.